# SQL query solution for getting statistics from my tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have been trying to get statistics from my tables. In the following, I have tried  to draw my table structure:
[image]

In the above, I have my **Transaction** table where each transaction is recorded for each user **Profile(profile_id)**. As well as, I record transaction created date **pub_date**, **transaction_type**(type options are shown in the circle) and transaction **amount**. When transaction created I give **Bonus** to each transaction with appropriate **Profile(profile_id)**.

So, I want to get statistics from above tables within the date range. More precisely:

1. Total transaction **sum amount** of each profile transaction within the date range with the **transaction_type**s of **WITHDRAW** and **WITHDRAW_MANUAL**.
2. Total transaction **sum amount** of each profile transaction within the date range with the **transaction_type**s of **DEPOSIT** and **DEPOSIT_MANUAL**.
3. Total Bonus **sum amount** of each profile transaction within the date range.

Visually, I want this result.
[image]

Here chosen date range means, I will give **startDate** and **endDate** period to the query

I could manage to solve **1.** and **2.**. But, I couldn't find way (for **3.**) to **SUM** of each profiles' **BONUS** amount within the date range. My solution is as followings:

```
 SELECT  mtd.profile_id, sum(mtd.amount) AS summa_deposit, 
  (
        SELECT sum(mtw.amount) AS summa_withdraw
        FROM public.main_transaction AS mtw 
        WHERE mtw.profile_id=mtd.profile_id AND mtw.pub_date>='2017-01-01' AND mtw.pub_date<='2017-10-01' AND mtw.transaction_type IN ('WITHDRAW','WITHDRAW_MANUAL')
    )
FROM public.main_transaction AS mtd
WHERE mtd.pub_date>='2017-01-01' AND mtd.pub_date<='2017-10-01' AND mtd.transaction_type IN ('DEPOSIT','DEPOSIT_MANUAL') 
GROUP BY  mtd.profile_id
ORDER BY mtd.profile_id;
```

Getting total amount of each profiles bonus is not a problem here. The problem is to get those amount within the **date range**. Because, I don't record date to my **Bonus** table. I only have my **transaction_id** and **profile_id**

P.S. my table is in the PostGreSQL.

Comment: Sample data (and perhaps a SQL Fiddle!) would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just need another `join` in a subquery?

```
(SELECT SUM(b.amount) AS summa_bonus
 FROM public.bonus b JOIN
      public.main_transaction mtw 
      ON b.transaction_id = mtw.id
 WHERE mtw.profile_id = mtd.profile_id AND
       mtw.pub_date >= '2017-01-01' AND
       mtw.pub_date <= '2017-10-01' AND
       mtw.transaction_type IN ('WITHDRAW', 'WITHDRAW_MANUAL')
)
```

I don't know if the filter on `transaction_type` is necessary.

Comment: Thank you for help. Yes here transaction_type unnecessary. But there is a relevance. That is another problem, which I think I can handle. :)